# Pass an object as a method parameter and then have the method return the same object

Tags: c#, .net

Please see the code below:

```
var MyViewModel = new MyViewModel();
var MyDomainModel = AutoMapper.Map<MyDomainModel>(MyViewModel);
MyDomainModel = service.DoSomething(MyDomainModel);
```

The MyDomainModel reference is overwritten with the return type from: service.DoSomething();

Should I be passing MyDomainModel by reference in this case or does it not really make much difference?

I am looking at a lot of code that was written like the above and I am wandering if there is a reason for it that I am not aware of.

Comment: Is `DoSomething` creating a new instance of MyDomainModel or is it just returning the instance it got as a parameter?

Comment: @rene, the latter.

Comment: The answer really lies in those methods. In order to call them and have it accomplish anything it's vital to know what the method does. And then, to add a level of complication, you can't assume that the previous developer did it for a good reason. Or they may have done it for a good reason that no longer applies. It doesn't even matter if they've been programming for a long time and have a title like "Senior Wizard Architect." But in order to know what to do (if anything) with the result of `DoSomething` you have to know what that method should do or return.

Comment: ok then in this case the catching of the return value is not necessary, because only the reference to `MyDomainModel` will be passed into the call of `DoSomething` , since it is not a value type or `struct` and the original object will be manipulated inside the method `DoSomething`. So after the call `MyDomainModel` will already be changed

Comment: No, it will not be "passed by reference" - that means something else. You are passing an object reference *by value*.

Comment: @Blorgbeard interesting wordplay :) thanx for the detailed correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as the comments indicate, `DoSomething` just modifies properties of the object passed in but returns the same object then you could replace

```
MyDomainModel = service.DoSomething(MyDomainModel);
```

with

```
service.DoSomething(MyDomainModel);
```

It doesn't matter because either way `MyDomainModel` will still refer to the same object.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought.  +1.  In that case I do not know why the developer returned the same object that was modified.  I won't get the opportunity to ask for a month or so.

Comment: It doesn't matter in the use case described, but something to consider is that using "ref" is also a valuable way to describe the intention for the method to modify the object passed to it.  Also, if "service" is something that could possibly cross app domain or machine boundaries, then marshaling could come into play and you could lose the benefit of having the modified object marshaled back because modification is not expected.  It's good to have a general rule of advertising when the argument is being modified by adding the "ref" calling convention, but better to return the modified object.

Comment: "ref" is a keyword that programmatically affects the behavior of code, so I'd only use it when I want that behavior. If I saw it I would understand that the method may alter my variable to refer to a different object, not that it will set properties on an object. If a method is going to alter properties of an object that can be indicated in the method or class name, the argument name, or XML comments. Also, if that's what it does then that's probably why the caller is calling it. But regardless, "ref" is not a comment. It's a keyword to use when you need what it does.

Answer (score 0):

if the `DoSomething` method is changing the input parameter *to point to a new object* then you must use `ref` otherwise I don't see the point of passing by `ref`.

**edit**

if as you've mentioned within the comments that you're only changing the state of the input parameter then there is no need at all to return the reference to the object that was passed in because the changes will remain intact after the method call.

in fact, whether the input parameter is being passed by `ref` or not there shouldn't be a reason to return the same reference of the object passed in. so, therefore, you can make the method `service.DoSomething(MyDomainModel);` return `void`.

Comment: DoSomething is returning the same object that was passed as an argument to the method (the object property values change).

Comment: yup then there is no need to pass by _ref_

Comment: And there's also no need to return it. Just change the `DoSomething` method to return void. Change its real name to make it obvious it mutates its parameter, if necessary.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, it has to pass the object to the service layer.  The service layer then calls methods on  MyDomainObject, which changes the state of the object before returning it to the client (MVC).

Comment: So.. why does that mean you need to return/reassign it?

Comment: @w0051977 if all you're doing is changing state, then that's fine. the issue comes into play **only** if you're reassigning the passed in  parameter to a new object.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, once the service layer is finished with the domain object; it is passed back to the client (MVC).

Comment: So is the same object (`object.ReferenceEquals()`) returned that was passed in or not? If it is, then you can return void.

Answer (score 0):

We have two possible cases here.

**The Original Instance is Modified**

```
public MyDomainModel DoSomething(MyDomainModel model)
{
    model.Property1 = X;
    model.Property2 = Y;

    return model;
}
```

Then you have to pass the original instance as argument but you can transform your function into a void since classes are passed by reference:

```
public void DoSomething(MyDomainModel model)
{
    model.Property1 = X;
    model.Property2 = Y;
}

var MyViewModel = new MyViewModel();
var MyDomainModel = AutoMapper.Map<MyDomainModel>(MyViewModel);
service.DoSomething(MyDomainModel);

// MyDomainModel.Property1 is set to X now...
```

**The Original Instance is Replaced**

```
public MyDomainModel DoSomething(MyDomainModel model)
{
    // ...

    return (new MyDomainModel());
}
```

In this case, if the method doesn't make any use of `model`, you can basically avoid passing it as argument:

```
public MyDomainModel DoSomething()
{
    // ...

    return (new MyDomainModel());
}

var MyViewModel = new MyViewModel();
var MyDomainModel = AutoMapper.Map<MyDomainModel>(MyViewModel);
MyDomainModel = service.DoSomething();
```

Otherwise, if the method creates the new instance keeping some retaining some properties of the old one, you have to keep it:

```
public MyDomainModel DoSomething(MyDomainModel model)
{
    MyDomainModel newModel = new MyDomainModel();
    newModel.Property1 = model.Property1;

    return newModel;
}

var MyViewModel = new MyViewModel();
var MyDomainModel = AutoMapper.Map<MyDomainModel>(MyViewModel);
MyDomainModel = service.DoSomething(MyDomainModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the method does. Objects are always passed by reference in this manner of use (though simply saying "passed by reference" doesn't really go far enough to explain what happens under the hood), so if DoSomething manipulates MyDomainMidel the changes will survive when the method returns. If, however, DoSomething makes a new domain model instance and returns it, and you want to preserve it, you have to keep the returned value

Here are some examples:

```
//the passed in person is renamed, you don't need to capture the return value
public Person Rename(Person p){
  p.Name = "John";
  return p;
}

//the passed in person is not renamed, you need to capture the return value
public Person Rename(Person p){
  p = new Person();
  p.Name = "John";
  return p;
}

//the passed in person is swapped out for a new one, you don't need to capture the return value
public Person Rename(ref Person p){
  p = new Person();
  p.Name = "John";
  return p;
}
```

The last example differs from the middle one thanks to the ref keyword. You can conceive that in the case if the middle call, you have a person in the calling method, you call `Rename (myPerson)` and the framework creates a copy of the reference to the person object, and passes the copy reference to the called method. If the called method manipulates properties of the instance then the original instance is modified even though it's accessed via a copy reference. If the copy reference is pointed to a whole new object, then any change to properties affect the new object, not the original. The copy reference goes out of scope when the method returns and the edits are lost as e copy pointer silently disappears, hence why you need to capture the return value if you want it

In the case of the ref keyword, rather than a copy of the reference to your myPerson being passed, the original reference to the instance is passed. If the method points it to a new object instance, then when control returns to the calling method, it will find its myPerson instance has been replaced with an entirely new object. The use cases for this are narrow, and it's not a favoured way to program because it essentially gives the called method the power to manipulate things beyond its scope of responsibility; the calling method might not appreciate having its variable contents trashed and replaced by a method call. There is nearly always a way to avoid using `ref` and while you're unclear on the mechanics of it, it is best to avoid using it, even if it does mean you have to code like the middle example.

You code like the middle example a lot, perhaps without realising; strings are immutable, so every call to e.g, `.Substring` creates a new string representing the shorter sequence of characters, so you have to keep the return value. As a result, some developers fall into the habit even for methods that only manipulate properties of an existing object and never use the `new` keyword